# how to use scroll to load data in custom div

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i want to load my data by scroll in my dialog ('.pm_content') 
i know about win.scrool but how i can use that just for my selected dialog?
my means i don't want to use window scroll i want to use scroll in '.dialogs ace-scroll'

This is a picture to clear what i want: http://screenshotuploader.com/s/1604yiir5

JS:

```
$(".pm_content").load('data.php');

var win = $(window);
win.scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {

        ....
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="widget-body">
    <div class="widget-main no-padding">
        <div class="dialogs ace-scroll">
            <div class="pm_content"></div>
        </div>                                      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the `$.scroll()` event to a window but you can use it with other containers too.

You can always bind the `$.scroll()` to a particular element instead of the window.

```
$("#yourElementId").scroll(function(){
   //whatever you wish
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Here you have an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/55wv6okg/

Comment: var win = $('.dialogs, .pm_content'); this is not work for me!

Comment: I modified your fiddle and updated the answer. The scroll on your fiddle wasn't the div's scroll but the window's. By default, an overflow is enabled so the inner div simply stretched. You can see this on your fiddle if you inspect the elements. That's why you have to limit the height of the div and change overflow to scroll. I also corrected the selector and removed the inner IF condition because it never works.